# OleDb concurrency violation during update

Tags: c#, oledb

I've a problem when I perform a table Update as follows

```
DbTable.GetChanges();
DbDa.Update(DbTable);
```

as I get the violation error:

> concurrency violation : Updated 0 of the expected 1 records

Here's how I create the Adapter:

```
OleDbDataAdapter DbDa = DB.GetAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Stats]");
DbDa.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true; 
DbDa.AcceptChangesDuringFill = true; 
using (DataSet ds = new DataSet(DbTabName))
{
    DbDa.Fill(ds, DbTabName);
    DbTable = ds.Tables[DbTabName];
}
```

My table *Stats* has the following structure

- ID Int AUTOINCREMENT (key)
- DATA String (key)
- CODE String (key)

I noticed that If I set only ID as Key, all works fine and I have no exception but, if I set also the other two columns (DATA and CODE) that violation error raise up.
I've tried also to specify key columns in InsertCommand but without success.

Comment: Why are you using the other columns as a key at all? There's no way you'd get duplicate ID values. The ID already identifies the row. I suspect your code modified either `data` or `code` too.

Comment: As for the exception itself, check [Optimistic Concurrenc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/optimistic-concurrency). Instead of using (extremely) expensive long-lived transactions to ensure data doesn't change while it's changed on the client, since the late 1990s all data stacks use optimistic concurrency. Before storing changes, they check if the stored data has changed since they loaded a record. If it has, they raise a concurrency exception. If you change the primary key values, the *wrong* record will be used for the comparison

Comment: I would try to add a line like this before entering the using block: _OleDbCommandBuilder ob = new OleDbCommandBuilder(DbDa);_ This will help the OleDbDataAdapter to correctly figure out what commands should be used to insert/update/delete your table. But still all the warnings and advices above are to be taken into account.